# Mysql usar store procedure en un select

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una duda, con db2 pude hacerlo, pero en Mysql, quiero hacer un select con un store procedure, algo como:

select venta.id,venta.fecha, obtenermontodeuda(venta.id) from xtabla where venta.deuda='S'

espero se entienda el ejemplo... ya intente con call y execute procedure antes de llamar a mi sp, pero no esta funcionando... Alguno tiene conocimiento si esto es posible en mysql? gracias.

Comment: Agrega tu procedimiento almacenado que llevas al momento así como los posibles errores obtenidos

Comment: Por cierto ¿qué es: `obtenermontodeuda`?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías usar una función en lugar de un store procedure, en esencia la función tiene un return el cual te traerá el dato que necesitas.

Comment: Buenas, pese a parecer que tu pregunta puede ayudar, lo mejor sería añadir algo de código explicativo para ayudar a comprender lo que quieres transmitir.